# Solving the differential equation $y' = y(1-y)e^{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to determine what the limit as $t$ goes to infinity of $y(t)$ is if $y(2016) = 2$ in the equation $y'= y(1-y)e^{y}$.

I'm assuming the equation needs to be solved first, unless I'm missing some trick. However, I'm not sure how to solve this as if I try to solve it as I would any standard separable equation, the integral is impossible.

Comment: Hint: $f(y) \stackrel{def}{=} y(1-y)e^y < 0$ for $y > 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @achillehui what does it mean in the question then when it says "suppose $y(2016) = 2$". In that function $f(y)$, that condition is obviously not satisfied. I'm really confused now.

Comment: It means in some point in time ($t = 2016$), $y$ is $2$. Since $f(y) < 0$ there, $y(t)$ will decrease as $t$ increases (as least when $t \approx 2016$). Now $f(1) = 0$ implies $y(t)$ can never drop below $1$. This means as $t \to \infty$, $y(t)$ need to converge somewhere between $1$ and $2$. Can you guess where it is and how to justify that?

Comment: Remark: though you can't solve the equation analytically, at large $x$ the function behavior can be well captured by $1 + C e^{-e x}$ in which $C$ is some constant. This is obtained by dropping small terms from the equation assuming $y$ small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(y) = y(1 - y)e^y$. Note that the equation $y'(t) = f(y(t))$ has two trivial solutions $y(t) \equiv 1$ and $y(t) \equiv 0$. By the uniqueness of the solutions, any solution that satisfies $y(t_0) = 1$ must be the constant solution $y(t) \equiv 1$.

Now, let $y(t)$ be a solution of $y'(t) = f(y(t))$ satisfying $y(2016) = 2$. By the continuity of $y$ and the observation above, we must have $y(t) > 1$ on $[2016,\infty)$ which implies that $y'(t) = f(y(t)) < 0$ on $[2016,\infty)$. Thus, $y$ is decreasing on $[2016,\infty)$ and has a limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(y) = C \geq 1$. This in turns implies that $y'(t)$ also have a limit given by

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} y'(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} f(y(t)) = f(C). $$

Finally, by the mean value theorem, we have

$$ 0 = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{y(t + 1) - y(t)}{1} = \lim_{t \to \infty} y'(t) = f(C) $$

which implies that $C = 1$.